# How do I merge table T1 (M x P) and table T2 (M x Q) by a common column ID in pandas such that the resulting table is T3 (P x Q)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have two tables T1 and T2 such that:

T1-where a,b,c,d are the counts of occurrences of certain types of data.

```
ID a b c d

1 0 0 1 0

2 2 0 1 0

3 0 1 0 4
```

T2- where x, y, z are the tests associated with the findings of those data points.

```
ID x y z

1 0 2 0

2 0 0 1

3 4 0 0
```

The resulting table should be:

```
   a b c d 

x  0 4 0 4

y  0 0 2 0

z  1 0 1 0
```

For example, in the output, the value in cell [1,4] is 4 because the number of tests of type x required to find data type d was 4.

The actual data contains 10,000+ ID's. I have tried using the merge function and the combine functions but I haven't been able to get the right results.

Comment: It's really unclear how the input data is supposed to turn into the result. I thought I could almost see it but why is column `b` all zeros in the result? 
Anyway, more examples of how to arrive to the values of the resulting table would be helpful.

Comment: Hi gereleth, that was a mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing it out! The position [1,2] in the table should be 4 as 4 tests of type x were associated with the finding of data type b too.